# Iptables newbie pain

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, iptables

I got a host (WINDOW7) and a guest (DEBIAN7.7) virtualized by VirtualBox. I configure an eth1 interface as host-only. My host can ping the guest and vice-versa, host can connect via ssh too. Now I want host accesss the guest's Wildfly instance, so I added this rule to iptables: `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT -i eth1`. If I execute `iptables -L` I can see the rule and Wildfly is up and running. Sadly, when I try to connect via host's browser to guest's wildfly I got an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian's Iptables keeps everything open by default. No need of rules. I only forgot to start Wildfly on the eth1 ip address. I run Wildfly again with this command: `./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0` and host can access Wildfly guest's instance. Happy ending.

Comment: This always happens to me with Apache, forget to turn it on xD